# PYTHON - why multiprocessing Pool using 100% of CPU?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I need to run a program in parallel, I used python `multiprocessing.Pool`
but the script execution used 100% of all 4 units which increased the CPU temperature.

Is there a way to limit the % used by pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count

```
cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Pool(processes=cpu_count // 2) # Use only half of the CPUs
```

And check your CPU fan.

Comment: the problem was that each unit is used 100%, even with simple python script, maybe the OS (linux) was the problem cause it work great in windows, thanks